# Progress of Intrinsic Dimension Calculation in R

Tags: r, dimensionality-reduction

I am using the R packages "ider" and "intrinsicDimension". Only one function in the "intrinsicDimension" package: pcaLocalDimEst, has a verbose option, none of the functions in the "ider" has a verbose option.

Is there any way to get the progress of the calculations?
For instance, if I use the kernel version of the correlation dimension estimator for determining the intrinsic dimension:

> estconvU <- convU(x=df, maxDim=20)

How do I obtain the progress of the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the following:

```
fix(convU)
```

Modify the first line, by adding `"verbose=FALSE"` to the end of the function call:

```
 # -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -vvvvvvvvvvvvv don't add this line
function (x, maxDim = 5, DM = FALSE, verbose=FALSE) # <- add this "verbose=FALSE"
 # -- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -^^^^^^^^^^^^^ don't add this line
```

Then, scroll down to line 19 and add the following AFTER the for loop initialisation:

```
19:  for (l in 1:maxDim) {
20:        if(verbose) cat(paste("Working...", l, "\n")) # Add this line.
```

Then click the **Save** button at the bottom. If you made a mistake, R will complain.

If not, call the `convU` function but add `verbose=TRUE` and you should see some progress messages appear. For example, from the help page of convU:

```
x <- gendata(DataName='SwissRoll', n=1200)
estconvU <- convU(x=x, verbose = TRUE)
Working... 1 
Working... 2 
Working... 3 
Working... 4 
Working... 5
```

Comment: Exactly what I was doing! Thanks for taking the time to write an elaborated answer. Very much appreciated. Also is it possible to make these changes permanent? Because it looks like I need to do this fixing procedure every time I start R !

Comment: It's only as permanent as your R session. Unless you save the function to a file and source it before using it again. The next step up is to save the function as a package and load this package like any other. :)